# An approach to porting a project to another platform

Tags: android, ios, porting

I am an intern at a company trying to push an android and iPhone out out within the next 5 months. Today, I received information about my first "real" assignment which will entail porting the iPhone App to the Android platform. Here's my problem though: I've never seen a single line of Objective C code and I only just started programming in Java and for Android devices last wednesday.
So how do I go about porting an application? Where do I start? How do I best organize myself and get an overview of which tasks to complete and when to start working on them ?

**tldr; How do I port an application to another platform?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word *porting* means in effect creating an application on another platform (in another language if needed) that maintains the same functionality.  As iOS and Android use different languages and internally very much different operating model, you cannot simply take iPhone code and translate it line-by-line into Android.

What you do need to do is analyse the functionality of the iPhone app and create an app for Android that will perform the same functionality. Do not approach this as a direct "porting" project, but rather as a new development project. You may be able to translate some business logic one-for-one - but anything related to the user interface (and, most likely, to any back-end server communication if you have any) will need to be written from scratch.  You may encounter certain things that are present in an iPhone but are not supported at all in Android, or are very complicated to implement, so try to think how to substitute them with whatever Android does support.

The biggest problem you'll encounter with Android is the multitude of screen sizes and versions, each of which may behave differently and support different things.  I suggest you start from the beginning and do one screen at a time, adding functionality step-by-step until you get the desired app.

5 months is a long enough period of time to complete the job for almost any app.  Good luck!

P.S. I have gone through this exercise myself: having an iPhone app I had to "port" it to android platform.  Using the approach I described, it took me about 2 months to complete the android app, which initially took about 3 months to create on an iPhone platform.